# Positivity conditions for $N^\dagger N$ where $N$ is a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Let $N: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be a positive linear map between two Hilbert spaces, $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. Define the adjoint map $N^\dagger$ as the linear map which satisfies for any $x\in \mathcal{A}$ and $y\in\mathcal{B}$

$$\langle y, N(x)\rangle = \langle N^\dagger(y), x\rangle$$

Under what conditions is the map $N^\dagger N$ a strictly positive map? That is, when do we have the condition below for any $x$?

$$\langle x, N^\dagger N x\rangle > 0$$

Comment: The closest you can get to $\langle x, N^\dagger N x \rangle > 0$ for all $x$ is if $N$ is injective. Then $N$ has only a trivial nullspace, so $$x \neq 0 \implies \|Nx\|^2 > 0 \implies \langle Nx, Nx \rangle > 0 \implies \langle x, N^\dagger N x \rangle > 0.$$

Comment: There seems something wrong with your definition of the adjoint map?

Comment: @Jakobian, sorry about that. Fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Theo Bendit suggests, we have $N^\dagger N > 0$ if and only if $N$ is injective.

If $N$ is injective then for $x \ne 0$ we have $Nx \ne 0$ so
$$\langle x, N^\dagger Nx\rangle = \langle Nx,Nx\rangle = \|Nx\|^2 > 0$$

Conversely, if $N^\dagger N > 0$, then for $x \ne 0$ we have
$$\|Nx\|^2 = \langle Nx,Nx\rangle = \langle x, N^\dagger Nx\rangle > 0$$
so $Nx \ne 0$. It follows that $N$ is injective.